# Adding dynamic widget with button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform

I am facing a strange bug when I try to add a dynamic widget to my app. When press add button screen turns completely white I can not find why it happens.
I use https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPW1vtDDlt4 as resource I am really new at Flutter maybe I forget something to add bu I check many times.
Here is my code,

```
class DynamicWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: new TextField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Press + to Add Field'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Initialization of the list.

```
  List<DynamicWidget> listDynamic = [];
```

My function to add widgets to the list.

```
  addDynamic() {
    listDynamic.add(new DynamicWidget());
    print("addDynamic");
    setState(() {});
  }
```

I am not sure but problem might be here,

```
final testText = Visibility(
  child: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Flexible(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listDynamic.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) => listDynamic[index],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Here I call my widget which I declare it to variable here.

```
final body = Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            testText,
            strPhoto
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And finally my button.

```
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(device_type), centerTitle: true),
        drawer: Menu(),
        body: body,
        floatingActionButton: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: null,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                addDynamic();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ));
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Are all of these code blocks in one file? If all of these are in one file, please update your question providing all of these code blocks into one code blocks. Because there might be problem where does your function, testText and others are povided.

Comment: I know which code block is doing what. But I'm asking for all of them in one code block. Because can be problem with your code formation. I've copied all of these code. But I can't run. It was showing error in `SingleChildScrollView`. So it will be helpful, if you put all of them in one code block.

Answer (score 0):

you must create variable Widget and add to Build Context on Scaffold

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

In the first step, i created a Widget called CustomTextField

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
final String hint;
final TextEditingController controllers;

CustomTextField(this.hint, this.controllers);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0, left: 6.0, right: 6.0, bottom: 2.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: hint),
                controller: controllers),
            SizedBox(height: 4.0),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
}
```

this widget give me one text for display on hint and one controller for control textfield

And in the next step, I change the homepage class this way
i have list of Custom TextField (my widget) and display on listview using mapping list of build method

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'CustomTextField.dart';

class PageTutorial extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageTutorialState createState() => _PageTutorialState();
}

class _PageTutorialState extends State<PageTutorial> {
  List<CustomTextField> widgets = [
    CustomTextField("UserName", TextEditingController())
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: widgets.map<Widget>((widget) => widget).toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              widgets.add(CustomTextField("Password", TextEditingController()));
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }
}
```

**have fun**